# Why is accuracy important in pricing American Options?

Tags: options, american-options

I see a lot of academic papers talking about accuracy in pricing American Options (and finding analytic solutions). Why is there so much interest in this topic? Isn't the option price set by the market? From what I can understand, accuracy in pricing gives accuracy in implied volatility, which gives you a sense of which options are expensive relative to others (eg. A listed puts for the same underlying, same maturity but varying strike may have different volatilities, even though they should be the same). I don't see why as an option trader accuracy is important, since the market already decided the fair price.

Comment: What about simulating future credit risks or market risk where you need to estimate portfolio value? Today option price can’t be used for future,

Comment: A pricer is useful for 2 things essentially: computing a price and calculating Greeks. If you cannot price the option with sufficient accuracy (+speed) you *a fortiori* have no means of computing your Greeks accurately (and fast), or put differently, no means of knowing the exact risks you are exposed to and thus decide the ones you want hedge vs. those you're comfortable with. Also a pricer can be useful to price non listed options (e.g. 5Y American call trading OTC)

Comment: @SmallChess Thank you for replying, what do you mean by that, and how does accuracy in option pricing help? Suppose you did have a purely analytic pricing of American Options. What could you do with that?

Comment: Option pricing is the low hanging fruit in academic research, it's easy to get the data.

Answer (score 1):

Accurate pricing of American options is useful in both situations, where the option is quoted (listed/exchange traded option), as well as where the option is not quoted (over the counter/OTC). Listed options are only available for specific underlyings, specific strike prices and specific maturities.

- For listed options, the accurate pricing will give you a reliable hedge for your option, typically via the delta greek. The most popular model is indeed Black-Scholes, because it is simple to understand, but there are variations, for example considering a term-structure of volatilities/rates. Slightly more fancy models such the local volatility model or stochastic volatility models are usually not used in this context.
- For OTC options, the pricing model may help you infer the price of the American option from European options prices. Yes, to quote a price, you don't necessarily need to be extra accurate (up to the cent may be enough), since you will add a spread anyway. The model also gives you a simple way to delta hedge and vega hedge your American options. Local/stochastic volatility models may offer here some interesting alternate price, which you can take into account to define your spread. Accuracy gives you some comfort that your implementation is reliable/theoretically sound. If your pricing is consistently too low under some circumstances, the counterparties may take advantage of it.
- In both cases, the greeks are often computed via numerical bump and revalue, and stress the accuracy of your implementation more.

Contrary to some of the comments, the American option price may be significantly different from its European counterpart. This typically happen when early exercise is often optimal (you are close to the early exercise boundary).

Answer (score 0):

The market creates price quotes only for some standard products. But maybe you have some products in your portfolio that are non standard (e.g. because the market has changed since you bought it).

Now you want to know what your assets are worth. What to write to your balance sheet? Or maybe you want to sell it. how much should you be payed? The market doesn't tell you directly. You have to to calculate it. And typically you want to know it exactly.

Comment: Aren't pricing models kind of subjective? Why should I trust the Black-Scholes equation?